# Sockets & Windows Service

Tags: java, android, sockets, windows-services, byte

theres a guy in my job that connects to a socket thru C using structs of bytes. How can i do the same in Android/Java. I know i can add more info, but i think i need a few answers to develop more into the right point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the java.net.Socket class.

Upd: getOutputStream() gives you an OutputStream instance. You can write byte arrays directly into it. To simulate C datatypes, you'll have to decompose your variables into bytes using shift and mask operators. For example, to write an int (assuming it's little-endian on the wire), use:

```
int n;
MyOutStream.write(new byte[]{n&0xff, (n>>8)&0xff, (n>>16)&0xff, (n>>24)&0xff});
```

For strings, use toByteArray() with the appropriate encoding ("US-ASCII" is not sure).

There's also the DataOutputStream class, which can do the same for you, but IIRC it writes a small header in front of the data, so the wire data will be incompatible with the existing protocol.

Comment: I'm succesfully establishing the connection and working with IO, but i dont know how to send packages of bytes.